# SQL Server 2008 - SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a database with over a 150 tables. I need to be able to find every table that has a column called `EmployeeID`. Is there a way for me to find all tables that have this column? It's kind of a long process if I go through each table and try to find if it has that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
select c.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where column_name = 'EmployeeID';
```

Comment: I'm curious - is there a benefit or 'good practice' reason for aliasing in this instance?

Comment: Nice blog @gordon linoff!

Comment: @AaronD . . . I generally give tables aliases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Understood - habit is a perfectly good reason.  Thanks for all of your great answers, Gordon.